# Locked posts - displaying up/downvote buttons

Tags: support, bug

Why some locked questions and answers display up/downvote button

> [image]

and some not?

> [image]

---

Tap the image to see what questions I am writing about.

 As Richard Tingle pointed, on mobile site both questions have their vote arrows shown.

Comment: Interesting,  could you link to the examples

Comment: @RichardTingle Edited, tap the image

Comment: Hmm, on mobile they both show up correctly (with voting arrows) but on desktop they show up as per your screen shot

Comment: @Azik that seems to be about why they show at all, rather than the inconsistency

Comment: @Azik Yes, it is not duplicate.

Comment: If I recall correctly only mod close voters can be contacted that way. However it pinged me and I threw in a reopen vote